# WAS 6 to WAS 8.5 migration

Tags: migration, websphere, server, ibm-was

I need to migrate my application to WAS 6.1 to WAS 8.5.5. I would need list of things to be taken care before migration and what are all the major changes involved.

I googled and sufficient informations I couldnt get. Can some one please help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to do is to setup an eclipse with [IBM WebSphere Application Server Migration Toolkit](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/downloads/migtoolkit/vtov.html) and then import your application source code (you may even analyse your binaries with [Migration Toolkit for Application Binaries](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/migration-toolkit-application-binaries-tech-preview/)) in the workspace.

You then run **Software Analyzer** and select the Websphere Migration rules.